# How can I convert a datetime object to the format yyyy\MM\dd in C#?

Tags: date, time, formatting

string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString(
            "yyyy'\'MM'\'dd",
             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

I need output : 2017\07\19

Comment: Specify the language...

Answer (score 0):

Should specify/tag a language, looks like C# though, try this here:

```
using System.Globalization;

string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Update:** Didn't notice you wanted backslashes instead, for that use:

`dt = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"yyyy'\\'MM'\\'dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: It doesn't work. dt = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"yyyy'\\'MM'\\'dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); this will give me 2017\\07\\20

Comment: I tried   string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"yyyy\MM\dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); this will give me "2017M7d20"

Comment: string dt = DateTime.Now.Year + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + "\\" + DateTime.Now.Day; this will give me 2017\07\20

Comment: Not sure what is causing the difference, I tested my answer and it worked.
I'd say try: 'string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString( @"yyyy'\'MM'\'dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);'. The '@' should take the string as a literal and not recognize the backslash escape sequence.